# Detecting typing outside of an input in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, so for our app we have a sidebar with a long list of all the different pages available to that current user. At the top of the sidebar is an input which, using Javascript, only shows options on the sidebar that contains the word(s) they searched for.
Is there any way of achieving this without actually having an input, or using a hidden input?

I want it so when the user types, as long as they aren't focused onto another input/textarea/whatever, it refines the sidebar. I'm not sure if you've seen the new MySpace but that's exactly what I'm going for.

Comment: I tried setting the focus to the search input on document ready, then hiding that input, but it won't register keyup/keydown events on an input hidden from the DOM.

Comment: @JoeyEmery Your efforts should be in included in your post. Your question should revolve around your own code, if possible. Just flat out asking for code is not encouraged on Stack Overflow. It's also very likely that an answer already exists in another post (or posts), as this is a relatively common issue. For example, [jQuery: How do I listen for general keyboard input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455274/jquery-how-do-i-listen-for-general-keyboard-input)

Comment: @Boaz I figured posting my code would have been of no use considering the question was more of a "what do I bind to?" rather than a "what am I doing wrong?". Understood though, my bad!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quick example to point you in the right direction. Every time a key is pressed the event is checked to see if it was activated in an input. If not the character code is logged to the console.

```
$('body').on('keypress', function(e) {
   if ($(e.target).is('input')) {
        return;
   }
   console.log(e.which);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for, never realised that the target was logged under the event (guess I've never needed it before).

Answer (score 2):

Listen to the `keypress` event on `document`. Then get the `target` from the event to determine if it's an input or similar.

```
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).is('input')) {
         return;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Again a perfect answer, but somebody beat you to it so I'm marking theirs as correct! Thanks though :)

Comment: Is their any difference in binding to the document instead of the body?

Comment: `document` is always available in JavaScript while `body` is a tag which you will need to wait for untill it is ready. So, you can also wait until the body is ready and then bind it to body.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [jQuery Hotkeys plugin](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys).

Comment: I had a quick look, however it looks like it's more for defining your own shortcuts, for example you have to specify something to match against (eg: "ctrl+a") instead of allowing any input.