# Which Language Should I Use To Code Keys On A Keyboard?

Tags: jquery, python, keyboard, key-bindings

How do you code keys on a keyboard? I am trying to make a game and I am wondering how I can assign keys a role. For example:

```
Spacebar = Splits in two
Q = Macro feed
I = Open/Close Inventory
...
```

I think I could use python for it but I'm not sure. My code for python would be:

```
n = 2
if(UserPress == Spacebar):
    CellSplits = True
    CellParts = n*2
```

And I thought jQuery might work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $(Cell) = $('.Cell')
    $('.Cell').mousefollow(Cell)
});
```

Also, This Game Will Be A Knock-Off of Agario.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455274/jquery-how-do-i-listen-for-general-keyboard-input

Comment: Okay Thanks! Now I know which one to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic syntax in jQuery is like this:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 32) {
    alert('You pressed space');
  }
  if(e.which == 81) {
    alert('You pressed Q');
  }
  if(e.which == 73) {
    alert('You pressed I');
  }
});
```

Or you might use a switch statement instead:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  switch (e.which) { 
    case 32: 
      alert('You pressed space');
      break;
    case 81:
      alert('You pressed Q');
      break;
    case 73:
      alert('You pressed I');
      break;
  }
});
```

Comment: what does e.which mean? Is it like what key it is assigned to?

Comment: e is short for event. You could also write it as `event.which` (but not `event.witch` because that's not a thing). The e.which property normalizes event.keyCode and event.charCode. It is recommended to watch e.which for keyboard key input. The numbers are just ASCII character codes which you can look up at a lot of websites.